# Get related data

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am studying Laravel, very beginner level. So, the idea is to implement `slug` url. There is `Category` model. The model can have infinite number of slugs. If I request the last one, I get the apropriate page. If I request another slug (oblolete), I get 301 redirection to the last one.

Category is parent-child hierarchy model. I need one-to-one relation with `CategorySlug` model, due to I don`t care about all previous slug values.

Migrations:

```php
class CreateCategoriesTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('title');
        });

        Schema::table('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('parent_id')->nullable()->after('id');;
            $table->foreign('parent_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }
}
```

```php
class CreateCategoriesSlugTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('categories_slug', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('value')->unique()->index()->nullable(false);
            $table->timestamp('created_at')->useCurrent();
        });

        Schema::table('categories_slug', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('category_id')->nullable()->after('id');
            $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }
}
```

Models:

```php
class Category extends Model
{
    public function children() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Category', 'parent_id', 'id')->
            orderBy('order')->
            with('children');
    }

    public function slug() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\CategorySlug', 'category_id', 'id')->
            orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->limit(1);
    }
}
```

```php
class CategorySlug extends Model
{
    /**
     * @return App\Category
     */
    public function category() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category', 'category_id', 'id')->with('slug');
    }

}
```

When I run next code in a controller, I expect that every `Category` will have filled `slug` attribute.

```
$categories = Category::where('parent_id', null)->with('children', 'slug')->get();
```

But in fact, only the first one has proper `slug`. Others have slug attribute equal to null. All `children` attributes are loaded fine.

I put the source to [GitHub](https://github.com/GHopperMSK/customer-first) repository. Among other things, there is seeds file.

Update:
Thanks to @marlon-ferreira I have made some changes:

```php
class Category extends Model
{
    ...

    public function slug() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\CategorySlug', 'category_id', 'id')->latest();
    }
}
```

Now, everything works fine! I prefer to use `hasOne` due to I don't like write `$category->slug[0]->value` instead of `$category->slug->value`. Is it ok?

Why can't I replace `latest()` by `limit(1) + orderBy('created_at')`?

Comment: Can you elaborate on "The model can have infinite number of slugs" and "I need one-to-one relation with CategorySlug". Does this mean a `Category` can have only 1 slug?

Comment: Technically, the category can has many slugs, but in fact I use only last one. All previous slugs are used only for redirection.
In other words, in the database we keep many slugs for every category record, but in Category model we know only about the very last slug.

Comment: I mean there isn't possible situation when we need more than one (the last) slug for single category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Returning only the last SlugCategory for all Category tree (root and children's)

This is my proposal:

On Category Model:

```
public function slug() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\CategorySlug', 'category_id', 'id')->latest();
}
```

1. You set the slug relationship as it is: One to Many (Category hasMany Slugs);
2. You call the `latest()` method to provide you only the latest slug.

With this approach, when you call `slug()` relationship, it will only retrieve the latest CategorySlug record.

On Category Model:

```
public function children() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Category', 'parent_id', 'id')->
            orderBy('order')->
            with('children', 'slug');
}
```

So, this controller call...

```
$categories = Category::where('parent_id', null)->with('children', 'slug')->get();
```

...will returns only the latest slug for the main category (parent_id = null), and also for all their children's.

#### WARNING - Infinite Eager Loading

After I provided you with my solution, I would like to talk about something that, usually, many Laravel/Eloquent developers do not know.

Basically, you're creating an infinite eager loading. Let me explain to you:

This is your Category model and their relationships:

```
Categories => Categories (children)
           => CategorySlug (slug)
```

And this is your CategorySlug model and their relationship:

```
CategorySlug => Category
```

1. You made CategorySlug model with a method that returns the Category model.
2. In this same method, you made your Category relationship returns WITH the associated slug.

Because of this WITH definition on your CategorySlug model, actually, you are just re-retrieving the same CategorySlug model.

This doesn't make sense, and also, create an infinite eager loading. Example explanation:

```
Category::find(1)->slug();
```

What will happen here is:

```
category will load slug -> slug will load category -> category will load slug -> ...
```

**This is an infinite eager loading.** It will cause an Database Timeout Exception.

To avoid it, just remove the `with` on your CategorySlug model.

It is not necessary, on my point of view.

Let me know if your requirements change and you really need this reverse relationship.

#### Tricks and Extra Knowledge

- **Oldest and Latest methods**

There are 2 methods which allow you to retrieve only the oldest or the latest record. Example:

```
$categories = Category::where('is_active', true); // we have many categories here

$last_created_category = $categories->latest(); // latest category created

$old_updated_category = $categories->oldest('updated_at'); // oldest category updated
```

Both methods accept a string as parameters, to identify which field must be sorted.

Default is `created_at`.

- **Scope strategy usage**

Scopes are a great way to create a custom reusable implementation.

Assuming your controller implementation, we could apply scope on the following case:

On Category Model -

```
class Category extends Model
{
    ...

    public function scopeWithoutParent($query) {
        return $query->whereNull('parent_id');
    }
}
```

On Controller -

```
$categories = Category::withoutParent()->with('children', 'slug')->get();
```

- **Always eager load your relationships**

This is a trick that maybe you could use on your project.

Basically, you're able to force eloquent to load the relationships without explicit call it.

On Category Model -

```
class Category extends Model
{
    ...

    protected $with = [ 'children', 'slug' ];

    public function children() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Category', 'parent_id', 'id')->orderBy('order');
    }

    public function slug() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\CategorySlug', 'category_id', 'id')->latest();
    }
```

On Controller -

```
$categories = Category::withoutParent()->get();
```

As you can see, you don't have to explicitly call the relationship anymore.

Hope this will be helpful.

Have a great day.